# How to implement CORBA client behind NAT

Tags: corba, nat

I have following interfaces.

```
interface Server {
   void subscribe(in Client client);
};

interface Client {
   void ping();
   void pong();
};
```

On initialization, client will connect to server and call subscribe(this). 
Then server will call time to time methods ping() or pong() on client. However, this will not work if client resides behind the NAT. What are possible workarounds for this problem?

Does it possible to utilize TCP connection created by client for calls server -> client?
please advise.

Answer (score 2):

Find out if your ORB supports bi-directional IIOP, that solves the NAT/firewall issue for server->client callbacks.

Here are some ORBs that do support it:

OmniORB - http://omniorb.sourceforge.net/omni40/omniORB/omniORB008.html#sec:bidir

Orbix - http://documentation.progress.com/output/Iona/orbix/migration/html/InteropCx3.html

Visibroker - http://www.albany.edu/dept/csi/csi518/fall03/inprise/vbroker/doc/books/vbj/vbj45/programmers-guide/bidir.html

Comment: TAO also supports BiDIR and also has some special flags to override the hostname/port that are put into the IOR

Comment: My ORB an server side is TAO, and this solution is exactly what I need. Thank you very much.